# How do we choose between "quand" and "que" in the following situation?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire

I came across the following sentences in a podcast text:

Les habitants ont confiance en ces institutions quand il n’y a pas de corruption, quand le gouvernement fait bien son travail et que les entreprises ne sont pas corrompues.

I wonder why the last sentence is initiated with "que les entreprises..." instead of "quand les entreprises..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Que* can be used as a substitute for another subordinating conjunction if this conjunction has already been used and if the second occurence (or third, or fourth, etc.) is linked to the preceding one by a comma or a coordinative conjuction (*et, mais, ou*). It is not mandatory and does not change the meaning, but makes the sentence more fluent because it avoids the repetition of the same subordinating conjunction. See [here](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/french-easy-learning/the-conjunction-que).

In your exemple, it would also be grammaticaly correct to write :

> Les habitants ont confiance en ces institutions quand il n’y a pas de corruption, quand le gouvernement fait bien son travail et quand les entreprises ne sont pas corrompues.

All the same, the second *quand* could already be replaced by *que*:

> Les habitants ont confiance en ces institutions quand il n’y a pas de corruption, que le gouvernement fait bien son travail et que les entreprises ne sont pas corrompues.

This substitution is very frequent and can be used in all kinds of speech, informal or formal, spoken or written.

Ex:

> Comme il avait besoin d'aide et qu'il est mon ami, je suis venu.
>
> Je suis venu, bien qu'il gèle et qu'il neige.
>
> Quand Jean vient à Paris mais qu'il n'a pas réservé de chambre d'hôtel, il dort chez moi.
>
> J'aime mettre cette chemise quand je sors ou que je vais au bureau.

Comment: Merci beaucoup! Quelle explication limpide!